# Unexplainable result of an expression

Tags: c++, expression

I'm currently working on a project where I've got stuck due to "out of range", "memory access violation" and other similar issues. Having spent much time trying to figure out where the problems come from, I came to a trivial piece of code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define RANDOM(min, max) min + RAND_MAX / ((RAND_MAX - 1) / (max - min))

int main() {
    std::cout << RANDOM(0, 500) << std::endl;
}
```

One compiler `clang` says `500`, that's what I expect it to say. Another one (`gcc` I guess, I use VS2017) says `504`. Later I found out that the value of `RAND_MAX` for the both is different and if I specify the same value for `clang`, it also says `504`. Here the value of `RAND_MAX` is `32767`.

I went to my `Python` shell to calculate the expression manually. So I typed in

```
0 + 32767 / ((32767 - 1) / (500 - 0))
```

and got the result `500.015259720442`. This is no way `504`. How is it possible?

Comment: Python 3 uses floating point division by default. Try using `//` for integer division: `0 + 32767 // ((32767 - 1) // (500 - 0))` gives me `504`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart a short write-up of that looks like an answer.

Comment: I considered it, but this question is kind of all over the place, and I'm not sure it would satisfy the OP. The `RANDOM` macro that returns a constant kind of has me worried. I'm just really not sure what the question is really asking.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Nope your answer explained everything! Just cast `RAND_MAX` and other variables in the macro to `double`, now everything is gone

Comment: Using such macros is a bad idea. In this example, result of this macro depends on whether `min` and `max` are floating point or integral types. I suggest using `constexpr` functions instead, in which you can specify parameter types properly, and also avoid recalculation when `min` is a complex expression.

Comment: @Cem I'm aware of side effects, I use such macros only if I'm sure what it is gonna be used for

Comment: @Kaiyakha I don't understand your question. You have c++ and integer division at work, so why would you expoect the same result as in python there? May you elaborate about this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This difference is caused by the different way theses two languages handle decimal numbers.

C++ compilers will use by default the int type when you have natural numbers in your code. However, since the int type does not allow decimal number, it rounds down to the nearest unit each time you make a division in your code that result in a decimal number.

Python on the other hand does not have this problem.

To specify that you want to use doubles in your code, you can do something like this :

```
std::cout << 0 + 32767.0 / ((32767.0 - 1) / (500.0 - 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the integer arithmetic. 32766/64 is 65. 32767/65 is 504.